# Seaborn swarmplot marker colors

Tags: pandas, seaborn

I have my data stored in the following pandas dataframe df.

[image]

I am using the following command to plot a box and swarmplot superimposed.

```
hue_plot_params = {'data': df,'x': 'Genotype','y': 'centroid velocity','hue': 'Surface'}
sns.boxplot(**hue_plot_params)
sns.swarmplot(**hue_plot_params)
```

[image]

However, there is one more category 'Fly' which I would also like to plot as different marker colors in my swarmplot. As the data in each column is made up of multiple 'Fly' types, I would like to have multiple colors for the corresponding markers instead of blue and orange.

(ignore the significance bars, those have been made with another command)

Could someone help me with how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following approach iterates through the 'Fly' categories.  A `swarmplot` needs to be created in one go, but a `stripplot` could be drawn one by one on top of each other.
`'Surface'` is still used as `hue` to get them plotted as "dodged", but the palette uses the color for the fly category two times.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

sns.set()
np.random.seed(2022)
df = pd.DataFrame({'Genotype': np.repeat(['SN1_TNT', 'SN2_TNT', 'SN3_TNT', 'SN4_TNT'], 100),
                   'centroid velocity': 20 - np.random.normal(0.01, 1, 400).cumsum(),
                   'Surface': np.tile(np.repeat(['smooth', 'rough'], 50), 4),
                   'Fly': np.random.choice(['Fly1', 'Fly2', 'Fly3'], 400)})

hue_plot_params = {'x': 'Genotype', 'y': 'centroid velocity', 'hue': 'Surface', 'hue_order': ['smooth', 'rough']}
ax = sns.boxplot(data=df, **hue_plot_params)
handles, _ = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()  # get the legend handles for the boxplots
fly_list = sorted(df['Fly'].unique())
for fly, color in zip(fly_list, sns.color_palette('pastel', len(fly_list))):
    sns.stripplot(data=df[df['Fly'] == fly], **hue_plot_params, dodge=True,
                  palette=[color, color], label=fly, ax=ax)
    strip_handles, _ = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
    strip_handles[-1].set_label(fly)
    handles.append(strip_handles[-1])
ax.legend(handles=handles)
plt.show()
```

[image: sns.boxplot with hue and second coloring for sns.stripplot]